# Holding down a key in lua

Tags: lua, keypress, cheat-engine

Is it possible to hold down a key in lua, for example 'a'? I don't mean pressing the key with doKeyPress(VK_A) and then looping it but actually holding it for a certain amount of time.

Comment: If possible, please add a tag for the library or framework you're using. `doKeyPress` is not part of standard Lua.

Comment: I use Lua Engine in Cheat Engine.

Comment: There is a tag for that. I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `keyDown()` instead.

https://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Lua:keyDown

You'll eventually want to do a `keyUp()` command to release it.

https://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Lua:keyUp

Either by triggering an event (a key or mouse click of your own)
or by using a timer to keyUp() after a specified time.

**Edit:**

https://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Lua:sleep

keyDown( VK_A )
Sleep( 5000 )
keyUp( VK_A )

Comment: local timeAdress = '[[[[[[["TmForever.exe"+00966E1C]+48]+A4]+1B4]+0]+238]+1C]+2B0'
local timer = readInteger(timeAdress)




I found out the pointer of the timer in the game.
My plan is to tell the programm:
If the timer is 0 then press button 'w' for 5000 milliseconds.
So after the timer reaches 5000 milliseconds,
it should release the key again. But i can't make it work. I tried
keyDown()  and keyUp() but with no success.